# Conditionals using filehandles in C++

Tags: c++, file, pointers, initialization

I'm working with a C++ library which makes extensive use of constructs like:

```
FILE *out_file1, *out_file2 ... *out_fileN;

//for some output files, but not all:
out_file1 = fopen( filename, "w" )

//later
if( out_file1 ) fprintf( ... )
if( out_file2 ) fprintf( ... )
```

This seems to work OK under g++ on OS X. When I run it on linux, however, I get segfaults. Checking through the code, out_file is often initialised to non zero values.

I've tried adding

```
out_file = NULL
```

but this doesn't seem to help - in fact, according to the debugger, it doesn't change the value of out_file.

Can anyone help as to:

Is this a recognised and sensible way to do file IO (i.e. using the file pointers in conditionals)

Why is the value of the pointer not being set to null?

How can I set it to null?

Just to be clear - I'm trying to change the code as little as possible, as I'm coding a wrapper to someone else's library. So, even if the general structure is a strange way to do things, I'd rather find a workaround which doesn't change it if possible.

**EDIT:**
Since this seems to be a reasonable, if outdated way to do conditional file IO, I can narrow the scope of my question to the second two out of three, i.e.

```
class IO
{
private:
    FILE* opFile

    IO()
    {
         //At this point, opFile == 0x40
         opFile = NULL; //At this point opFile is still 0x40
    }
}
```

So obviously, if it comes out of the constructor with a non-null value, anything like:

```
if( opFile ) fprintf( ... )
```

will fail. But how is it managing to come out of the constructor with a non-null value?

And in case it helps, this works "as expected" under gcc on OSX, but not g++-4.3 or g++4.4 on Ubuntu.

Comment: According to the documentation for fopen() it should be returning NULL if the open fails, so the conditional should work as is. You probably have a bug elsewhere in the code which is causing undefined behaviour. Can you make a minimal working example that still shows this problem?

Comment: Just nitpicking but it seems you're dealing with C code, not C++...

Comment: Right, but fopen is not always being called - the plan is that files which are not opened are null, so it doesn't try to write to them.

Comment: RE C vs C++ - the code is a horrible mixture of both :(

Comment: what is "maybe do"? Does that mean that it does not get called in all cases?

Comment: I'm stepping through with gdb, and finding some very strange behaviour. That's how I know that the file pointer is *not* being set to null by "out_file = NULL". After that, the pointer still has a value of 0x40, so when it tests it and then tries to write, the test succeeds, and it segfaults on the write

Comment: Yes, "maybe do" means it is not called for all files - I'll edit for clarity

Comment: I'm not sure this helps you, but does it sound similar: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/compiler-bugs-in-g-4-3-3-strange-behavior-at-run-time-765861/

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is elsewhere in the code, most likely in the *printf calls you mention?

Show us more code, or use a debugger to find where it crashes.

```
g++ -O0 -Wall -g mysource.cpp -o test
gdb ./test
(gdb) run argument1 argument2
```

Also, look at valgrind for additional memory checking tools

```
valgrind ./test
```

$0.02

#### Update

Added -O0 to avoid confusing analysis with results of proper compiler optimization :)

Comment: +1, valgrind is very handy for finding the real cause of problems like this.

Comment: I'll have a go with valgrind, thanks. I know exactly where it crashes. And I know why it crashes - the file pointer is not null, despite never having been assigned to. And I can step through the constructor, and watch it ignore instructions to set the pointer to null.

Comment: A pro tip: never deny a problem if your want to solve it. [`Select isn't broken`](http://lingpipe-blog.com/2007/06/27/select-isnt-broken-or-horses-not-zebras/)

Comment: I'm not denying anything here (apart from this sentence). I'm 100% assuming that the fault lies with my program - I just can't figure out where!

Answer (score 1):

in *C++*, you should use iostreams, will help you avoid all these issues...

```
std::ifstream in ("some_file");

if (in)
{
  // do stuff with stream...
}
```

Comment: +1, this is by far the nicest way to do this although the OP did ask for "minimal changes to existing codebase"

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I can't really make changes on this scale

Answer (score 1):

Is this the actual code from your program?

```
FILE* out_file1, out_file2 ... out_fileN
```

Then only `out_file1` is a `FILE*` and all the rest are just `FILE`. That would explain their "funny values".

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you should use `std::fstream`(or `std::istream`/`std::ostream`) for file-IO, unless you have a very good reason not to. Then you would most likely not have this problem, as you could just write this:

```
std::ifstream file("myfile.txt");

while(file) { // this checks for any error
    // do stuff with file
}
```

Comment: Again, I would love to do it properly, but I can alter the code on this scale.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the compiler is optimizing your code. Assigning out_file to NULL a moment before it gets assigned to by the return value of fopen is pointless. The compiler might know that and not bother assigning NULL.

You could define and initialize the value on one line:

```
FILE* out_file = fopen( filename, "w" )
```

But, this won't make your problem go away. As somebody commented, you might be looking at the wrong bit of code as there doesn't appear to be much wrong with this.

You could try creating a minimal app that does just the operation you want and see if that works ok before reintroducing the rest of the code.

Comment: I've just clarified above that the problem is that fopen is not called for all the files (depending on the config). So I want to make sure that for all files it is not called for, the pointer is null.